# XML Schema - mixed element with restriction on it's content

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I've got the XML element that looks like this:

```
<text>
    Some text
    <subtitle>other text</subtitle>
    and some other text
</text>
```

And it's decleration in XSD looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="text">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="subtitle" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to put the restriction that the text inside the 'text' element should only be type of xs:string, how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't place restrictions on the content of text nodes in mixed content, except by using XSD 1.1 assertions. But since `xs:string` imposes no restrictions anyway, I can't see why this should be a problem.